# How to send unicode character sms into mobile using asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net

```
SenditemsTableAdapter sen = new SenditemsTableAdapter();
RegistrationTableAdapter reg = new RegistrationTableAdapter();
SendSMS sendsms = new SendSMS();
```

Here using tableAdapter

```
DS.RegistrationDataTable rtable = reg.GetDataByUsername(Session["username"].ToString());
    if (rtable.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        DS.RegistrationRow rrow = (DS.RegistrationRow)rtable.Rows[0];

        int smscount = Convert.ToInt32(sen.Sumcredit(Session["username"].ToString()));
        string username = rrow.Username;
        // int smscount=0;
        string MainString2 = txtmobileno.Text;
        string[] Split2 = MainString2.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
        string sendid = rrow.Senderid;
        int CreditLmt = rrow.Creditlimit;
        if (smscount <= CreditLmt)
        {
            if (rrow.Validitydate >= Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString()))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Split2.Length; i++)
                {
                    int credit = txtmessage.Text.Length / 160;
                    credit++;
                    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
                    SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(con);
                    connection2.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd1 = null;

                    string str = " insert into [Senditems] values('" + username + "','" + sendid + "', '" + Split2[i] + "',N'" + txtmessage.Text + "','Request.Url.AbsolutePath',' Request.UserHostAddress','Request.Browser.Platform + Request.Browser.Browser', '" + credit + "','" + date + "')";
                    cmd1 = new SqlCommand(str, connection2);
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    string message = Convert.ToString(SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(con, CommandType.Text, "SELECT message FROM senditems WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id)  FROM senditems)"));

                    sendsms.send(message, Split2[i], sendid);
                    connection2.Close();
                                       }
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "", "<script>alert('Your message send successfully');</script>", false);
                reset();
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "", "<script>alert('Cant send sms because your validity is expired');</script>", false);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "", "<script>alert('Cant send sms because you dont have credit');</script>", false);
        }
    }
```

In the button click events i have using " sendsms.send(txtmobileno.Text, Split2[i], sendid);" this method for send sms to mobile.

```
 strUrl = "http://onlinesms.in/api/sendValidSMSdataUrl.php?login=" + user + "&pword=" + pass +
                   "&msg=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Message) +
                   "&senderid=" + sendId +
                   "&mobnum=" + mobNum;

    WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(strUrl);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream s = (Stream)response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(s);
    string dataString = readStream.ReadToEnd();
    response.Close();
    s.Close();
    readStream.Close();
```

And using this url to send sms.I have insert message into table is properly and i can get message to mobile ok but getting message ???????????? like this . 
I want get sms properly pls any bady help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it all depends of how the website API is converting back your URL string.  In my opinion, I think it is safer to use the `Uri.EscapeDataString()` function instead of the `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` because in a `space` you get the `%20` instead of the `+` sign which may screw up your message.